# symfony api regresa jsons vacios

Tags: php, json, symfony, doctrine

Estoy aprendiendo como funciona Symfony tratando de hacer una api, el problema es que cuando quiero regresar un json con todos los registros de una tabla me los regresa vacios, esto es lo que eh intentando hasta ahorita:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Users;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/users', name: 'get_users')]
    public function get_all_users(ManagerRegistry $doctrine): JsonResponse
    {
        try {

            $entity = $doctrine->getRepository(Users::class);
            $users = $entity->findAll();
        
            if (!$users) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                    'No se encontraron usuarios'
                );
            }
    
            return new JsonResponse([
                'success' => true,
                'code'    => 200,
                'data' => $users,
            ]);

        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
             return new JsonResponse([
                'success' => false,
                'code'    => $exception->getCode(),
                'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Pero cuando regresa el objecto lo regresa con jsons vacios, alguna idea de como regresar la información de forma correcta?, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Estás devolviendo un objeto de tipo User directamente. Necesitas serializarlo previamente. Echale un vistazo a la página de  [documentacion](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) del Serializador de Symfony.